# Tokens exposed - refresh them?

Tags: google-drive-api

I was wondering if Google Drive API has any sort of 'disaster recovery' system in place? For example, in case of emergency if the tokens in my app get exposed I need to be able to re-create the tokens without prompting every user to accept/re-accept permissions again so the users' information doesn't get leaked. I really need this in order to provide my users a secured environment.

For example, I saw in the Box API that they provide an access token and a refresh token. Every time the access token expires they tell you to request a new one through the refresh token, and in that case both access and refresh tokens change. That would be ideal for us because we can run a script to request new tokens for each account we have, and then store in our DB the new tokens.

Regards, 
Andrew

Comment: What is the threat model? How are you expecting the tokens get exposed?

Comment: It is a potential scenario where someone gets access to the refresh tokens and I want to make sure I can let the users keep working safely and secure without prompting them again to grant permissions

Comment: That's a really bad idea. See below.

Answer (score 0):

[Google's OAuth2 also gives you both an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp), and the refresh token is used to generate new access tokens.

However, if the refresh token needs to be revoked, the user will need to reauthenticate.

---

The real underlying question though is, *what happens if the security tokens are exposed*? (Good for you thinking about this in advance.)

You need to do three things:

- Immediately revoke the tokens.
- Promptly, tell the users that their accounts were breached.
- After you're sure the breach has been remedied, ask the users to reauthenticate.

Why do I say you *need* to?

- In my opinion you have a moral obligation to tell them that an attacker may have gained access to their data.
- In some locales you may have a legal obligation.
- The [Google API terms](https://developers.google.com/terms/) say you must *promptly report to your users*, and you may permanently lose access to the API if you do not.

Making multiple refresh tokens in advance seems like a bad idea:

- You're assuming an attacker will cooperate in taking only one token?
- The user will need to authenticate repeatedly to generate them.
- You need to notify the user anyhow.

Comment: No way to revoke it and create a new one without reauthenticating?

Answer (score 0):

*Note:  I am going to assume that your application is using Google's [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Applications flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and that you are not using a service account.*

When you first ask the user to authorize your application (by redirecting them to the OAuth consent page) and include the `access_type=offline` parameter, you will receive both an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.  That `refresh_token` is valid **until it is revoked**, either by the user visiting their Account Settings page or by your application calling the `revoke` method.  Even if your application later receives another `refresh_token` for the same user, *the previous refresh_token remains valid until revoked*.

Therefore, if you have reason to believe that a user's `refresh_token` has been exposed, the safest course of action would be to revoke it and send the user through to OAuth flow again (providing the `approval_prompt=force` to ensure that you get another `refresh_token`).

Comment: So I can create multiple refresh tokens and then revoke the old ones? That would be an ideal solution for my suggested scenario

Comment: And yes I do use OAuth 2.0